# How do I split the comma separated string in my text file and save each string in different variable?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

These is the content of my txt file which is saved in D drive in my pc

```
abc,1,2,3
```

I tried the flowing but it didn't work:

```
Dim stats() As String = File.ReadAllLines("C:/myfile.txt ")

Dim data() As String = line.Split(","c)
Dim query = From line In stats

Country = Data(0)

States = CInt(data(1))

noOfcoders = CInt(Data(2))

rank= CInt(Data(3))

holidays = CInt(Data(4))
contribution = CInt(Data(5))
```

edit

I am getting error on this line.. data = line.Split(","c)...it says this line isn't in use anymore or something and that I rather use LineInput but thats asks for filenumber and i don't know what that is. I am sorry but I am a complete beginner. what else can I try?

Exact error that I am getting:-

> Error  1   'Line' statements are no longer supported. File I/O functionality is available as 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.LineInput' and the graphics functionality is available as 'System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawLine'.   F:\My Documents\Mark Sanchez\Programming with lab (VB.net)\CIS170A_Lab07\CIS170A_Lab07\Form2.vb 62  16  CIS170A_Lab07

---

**ok that error is gone now but now if I want to add these values to a list box..how can i do that?**

Comment: What error do you get? By the way, your file example has four fields but you reference six in your code.

Comment: Please explain what "didn't work" means exactly.

Comment: Can you be more specific? "Did not work." How/Why didn't it work? Is there an exception? If so, what's the message?

Comment: @Grand - I am getting error on this line..  data = line.Split(","c)...it says this line isnt in use anymore or something and that I rather use LineInput but thats asks for filenumber and idk wat that is. I am sorry but I am a complete beginner : / what else can I try?

Comment: Run the code again and paste the exact error message into your question.

Comment: How is this a C# question?  The problem is with your linq syntax, and as a C#/VBA/VB6 programmer I can only guess at VB.NET linq syntax.

Comment: @phoog Good point. I re-tagged for everyone's sake.

Comment: @phoog I thot I can use file reading code of c# and convert that and use that in my vb code : /

Comment: Please do not use any chat slang, leat, etc. on SO.

Comment: First off, if the answer is correct for your original question, accept it. Second, if you have a new question, ask a new question. *But* you should make sure the new question is a proper question showing what you have tried and where you are specifically having trouble. Your course materials and lecture should be a good starting point for what you need.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're reading a text file into a string array by line.

`stats` is not a string, it's an array of strings. Each item in the array is a string representing a single line from the text file.

Since you only have a single line in your file, there is only a single entry in the array.

```
Dim stats() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:/myfile.txt ")
Dim firstLine as String = stats(0)
Dim data() As String = firstLine.Split(","c)

Country = Data(0)
States = CInt(data(1))
noOfcoders = CInt(Data(2))
rank = CInt(Data(3))
holidays = CInt(Data(4))
contribution = CInt(Data(5))
```

@GrandMasterFlush is correct, too: Your code is referencing 6 fields, but your text file snippet only has 4 values, so this code will still fail.